# pyTelegramBotAPI and Selenium. Dynamic keyboard

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, telegram-bot, py-telegram-bot-api

I am trying to automate the creation of advertising campaigns using selenium and python telegram bot api.
I have select with a lot of options. I need to get every option and place it to the pytelegrambotapi inline keyboard.
I’m getting options from select tag like In code below using Select class. But i am not sure how to add all options to keyboard dynamically. Can you help me to solve this issue?

```
 def select_aff(message, index=None):
    # get <select>
    select = Select(browser.find_element_by_xpath(
        '//*[@id="formly_1_vAffiliateNetwork_affiliate_network_id_1"]'))
    # select.select_by_value()
    options = {o.text for o in select.options}
    # option = options[index]
    # select.select_by_visible_text(option)

@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: get_state(message) == OFFER_SELECT_AFFNETWORK)
def handle_select_affnetwork(message):
    if message.text == 'Select':
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Select affiliate network')
        select_aff(message)  # ADD DYNAMICALLY FROM KEYBOARD
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for this case. I decided to not use InlineKeyboard and I used ReplyKeyboard. Solution you can check in my github repo for this project. [Keitaro_bot repo](https://github.com/Infvmous/keitaro_bot/blob/master/app.py)